# What can I do when a postal company lies about a delivery being made?

Tags: online, shipping

Imagine I ordered a product online, and it gets shipped from China to Europe. One day, the tracking service offered by the chinese postal company claims that the package was successfully delivered and given to the recipient, when in fact, no such thing has occurred.

Upon contacting the seller, the seller claimed that the product was delivered by the chinese postal service, using their tracking service as evidence.

In such a hypothetical scenario, what would my options be? I'd have no way to prove a negative, or that I did not receive the package. Indeed, the seller could believe that I was lying and wanted a refund while keeping my package.

Comment: Generally your contract is with the person/company you purchased the goods from, not with the shipping company they use. But if buying through an online marketplace your contract might be with the marketplace, or you may be able to raise an action through the marketplace. You should check the conditions of sale and see exactly who your contract is with; you would have to sue them. If it genuinely is a hypothetical, then the answer is, it depends.

Comment: Yes, it's genuinely hypothetical. I was wondering that, since both buyer and seller can act in good faith, yet believe the other party is acting fraudulently.